# error with magento checkout

Tags: magento

I have this error when I try to checkout on magento. Can anyone help me with it ?

```
Invalid method Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Billing::isTaxvatEnabled(Array(
)
)
```

Comment: Probably not, not with the little information you provide. What is the context of the code that this occurs in?

Comment: it's when i try to checkout, ie when i press checkout - sorry i dont know what more information - it's magento 1.5.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have a corrupt Magento filesystem. I would recommend downloading a fresh zip file from www.magentocommerce.com and unzipping it over your base install to make sure you are on a fresh base of Magento. Then clear the cache and see if that fixes it. The file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Billing.html should contain an isTaxvatEnabled function.

Comment: Thanks mark - I hadn't realized it was OK to unzip an installation on top of an existing one ( would that mean that i would leave the database untouched and that all the products and categories should be intact ? ) .... I must be living in the dark; is this a standard practice ?

Comment: Yes, it should be OK as long as you haven't touched core code (you shouldn't be doing this anyways!). That is normally how you would upgrade a Magento install -- standard practice.